# How to remove empty metavar square brackets from python argparse help command?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I dont want to show default metavar in the help page nor I need to provide anything, so hack is to add an empty string as a metavar value, but it produces an empty square bracket in the help page, can anyone help how to remove it?

```
    required.add_argument(
        '--configure',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        metavar='',
        const='default',
        dest='configure',
        default=argparse.SUPPRESS,
        help='Configure a profile',
    )
```

Output:

```
mycommand profile --help                                                       
usage: command profile [--help] [options]

optional arguments:
  --list          Shows list profiles
  --configure []  Configure a profile
  --delete []     Delete a profile
  --show []       Show a profile
```

Answer (score -1):

The use of `[]` is integral to using `nargs='?'.  They mean "optional/not required".

```
In [626]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [627]: a = p.add_argument('--foo',nargs='?')
In [628]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [FOO]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --foo [FOO]
```

To change that you'll have to subclass the `HelpFormatter`, and change one of the nested methods.